# Link sharing on facebook using graph api(PHP Code)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook application for sending messages.I am posting some content and image to my wall using php facebook feed code.Normally when i post something on my wall it will visible on my friends news feed.But my wall post is not visible on my friends news feed. The code for posting wall is

```
$attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $AccessToken,
    'message' => "$Msg",
    'name' => 'some content',
    'link' => $link,
    'picture' => "$ShareImage",
    'description' => '',
    'caption'=>'',
);
```

So i remove the hole content and rebuild the code like this

```
$AccessToken       = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
        $attachment = array(
        'access_token' => $AccessToken,
        'message' => 'http://www.mysutec.com/stie/test',
        );
        $send = $this->facebook->api("/".$fbid."/feed", 'POST', $attachment);
```

Then also the the content is not showing on friends wall.But in facebook developer document they mention `link sharing`

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/
```

How i can implement this using graph api(php)

Comment: this can be a good start for u http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: The  only problem i am facing is the post is not showing on friends news feed..

Comment: if you are posting feed on your friends wall, i see you need to have element "to" as defined in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue `POST` request to Graph API to post/create content.

```
$params = array(
  'link' => 'www.example.com',
  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
);
$response = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $params);
echo 'Post ID: ' . $response['id'];
```

You also does't need to explicitly pass `access_token` in your case since PHP-SDK will use one for current user automatically.

You should read PHP-SDK documentation for [`Facebook::api`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) method which have posting of link as one of the samples.

Comment: Thanks Juicy Scripter The posting is working fine.. But the post is not showing on friends news feed..

Comment: Do you get any error? Is response contains `id` of created post?

Answer (score 0):

Why ask this question twice? i answered it on your other thread : 
[Another method for sharing link on facebook wall using Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8740365/another-method-for-sharing-link-on-facebook-wall-using-graph-api)

posting via /me/feed gives you message a lower ranking then posting an image/link .. this is why you sometimes won't see it on your friends news feed...

Cheers!